# Thread Pool Mutex Usage

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, mutex

I am working on a Thread Pool and have been trying to work out the best way to handle thread safety. I would like to know if my mutex usage is "Correct" and if not how I should change it. I am using the c++11 `std::thread` and `std::mutex`.

this is the Worker Threads function. It Locks on the first line.

```
void Worker::work(void){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mutex(_lock);
    while (_working) {
        while (!_tasks.empty()) {
            Job_t* job = _tasks.front();
            if (!job->Complete()) {//the same job cannot be scheduled twice. It must be finnished before it is scheduled again.
               (*job)();
            }
            _tasks.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

this is My `Job` classes function that does whatever "job" the job was created to do.

```
void operator()(void){
        _returnValue = func(_args,sequence_generator::gen_seq<sizeof...(arguments)>{});
    }

template <typename... Args, int... Is>
    returnType func(std::tuple<Args...>& tup, sequence_generator::_index<Is...>)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mutex(_lock);
        _complete=true;
        return _function(std::get<Is>(tup)...);
    }
```

There is a lot more to the design so i will post a link to my git repo for the project.

I would like to know if having the function `work()` lock and then having the `func()` lock as well is needed or even a good idea?

here is the [repo](https://github.com/zyvitski/Thread_Pool)

EDIT:
So the call order evaluates out to be...

```
Worker::work();
//which internally calls the 
operator()();
//which internally calls the 
func();
```

Comment: So... `(*job)();` happens *while you're holding the lock on the mutex*? What are you writing, a Python interpreter?

Comment: @KerrekSB It is a Thread Pool, Did you look at the code on the Repo I posted the link to? The design is much more complex than what I could have put in the question without getting very verbose. And about your question... the function `work()` locks around the function call to the `operator()()` which calls `func()` which locks around its code.

Comment: What @KerrekSB is trying to say is that usually, you want to keep a lock held the shortest possible time. You do what you want, of course, but his concern is that while the lock is held there might be other worker instances waiting for it, which isn't what you would want in theory.

Comment: Then, if that lock is only tied to some piece of information in your worker workload, it would perhaps be a better choice to move the locking closer to the places where that value is being modified.

Comment: (apologies if you know all this stuff already).

Comment: @didierc no apologies needed. The function `work` is calling anywhere from 0 to n functions (n being however many functions are scheduled) within its locked section. So in theory that lock is protecting the data that is the task that the worker has. Then the function `func()` is locking to protect whatever data pertains to that call so I thought that locking in both places was a good idea but I wanted to ask and see if someone with more experience that I have had any input.

Comment: A calling `thread` must not own the mutex prior to calling `lock` or `try_lock`. That's from the documentation on `std::mutex` (see : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)

Comment: @didierc can you explain that in more detail? Preferably in my situation. I will note that they are two separate locks in separate objects, they just have the same name.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't catch that - My bad. Then What's the purpose of the outer lock,if you have an inner lock already protecting the task? You really don't need it apparently.

Comment: @didierc there is data associated with the `Worker` class that is used in `Worker::work()` that I believe needs protection, in my opinion.

Comment: which data? Is that the task list? How come this list is shared? And if it is shared, why do you share it, since it's only being used by 1 thread at once?

Comment: @didierc I thinks you are probably correct on this one.

Comment: My guess is that you want to let each worker poll from the list, and to have that correctly happen in a multithreading environment, you must add protection to it. That's probably what you wanted to do with the `_lock` variable, but as it is right now, it locks the whole function, whereas you'd want it to lock access to its methods (`front`, `pop`, `empty`).

Comment: My advice would be thus to do just that: move the lock from the worker class into the class of `_tasks`, deriving it into a 'thread safe' version if necessary, with locking on each of this methods.

Comment: @didierc If you move your suggestions to an answer I will accept it. I feel that you have helped with my issue and have answered my question.

Comment: A most bizarre model for mutual exclusion. So it is *intentional* that a worker acquiring this mutex shall *never* give it up until the list is exhausted? It is somewhat the point of a thread pool to *distribute* the work (in this case the jobs in your task list) among multiple threads if, in fact, each task is mutually exclusive? from the other tasks. If some ordering must be maintained then perhaps a different queue structure is in order. Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig it is bizarre, I am new to dealing with threading and it didn't seem like I was approaching it correctly which I why I am here trying to sort out the best way to be doing what I'm doing.